# A vector of class objects, and their instantiation

Tags: c++, class, object, vector, std

Ok so i want a std::vector of class objects.
They will be made on demand.

```
std::vector<VertexBuffer> vBuffs;

somwehere::someFunction()
{
   VertexBuffer vB;
   thisNthat = 10;

   vB.thisNthat = thisNthat;
   ......
   vBuffs.push_back(vB);


}
```

Since vB goes out of scope, what happens to vBuffs[vB location] buffer?

What is the best way to do what i am trying to do.

```
vBuffs.push_back(VertexBuffer());

??
```

Then just assign values via the vector? (or constructor).

Answer (score 1):

> *"Since vB goes out of scope, what happens to vBuffs[vB location] buffer?"*

Since the `push_back()`

```
vBuffs.push_back(vB);
```

puts a **copy** of `vB` to `vBuffs` it's no problem that it goes out of scope at the end of the function.

Comment: If the class contains pointers is that a problem? I have written a copy constructor that copies pointers like this :  *pVB = *copy.pVB;

Comment: @Rear-AdmiralFluff It your class is broken, that's a problem. But `std::vector` is not generally broken (some might argue the `std::vector<bool>` specialization is, but that is another matter.)

Comment: @Rear-AdmiralFluff That's a different case and your copy constructor is probably wrong. To maintain pointers in classes properly, you should obey [The rule of Three](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three).

Comment: Broken usually is a problem, why is there something here which gives you that impression? Does *pVB = *copy.pVB present a problem?

Comment: @Rear-AdmiralFluff Depends on how memory management is done for these members. But as I mentioned, thats a different question, not what you've been asking for in this one.